# iOS - Detecting calls, cancel them an then do something

Tags: ios

Is it possible for one to make an app which listens for call events, if a number is equal to something, then cancel the call and do other stuff?

EDIT:
Some people are asking why I would wanna do this when it's such a simple question that, I'm having difficulty in understanding the negative feedback. As the question states, I just wanted to capture the call events and if the number dialed was equal to a specific number, than the call wouldn't proceed and I would do something else instead. The question is not too broad (unless I have to place the whole requirements engineering of the app) neither a complicated one. Just a simple question of "is this possible in iOS?".

As already answered by some helpful people (fortunately), it's not possible.

Comment: Do you mean make an app that a user downloads from the app store that will hang up a call that the user makes?

Comment: Why the [tag:ios7] and [tag:ios5] tags?

Comment: As I said, I just started iOS dev. So maybe this was compatible in ios5 or ios7. I simply don't know, since I've researched it and didn't find any answer.

Comment: Fennelouski, an app that the user downloads, cancels the call he made to a specific number and does something different without actually making the call to the number.

Comment: No, this is not possible on iOS. Apple does not allow apps to interact with the system at this level. You will only be able to build such a tool for jailbroken devices.

Comment: problem is your question doesn't follow the guidelines for stackoverflow. Correct format is; here is my coding problem, here's what I have tried, with example etc. This is the wrong forum for "is it possible to make an app.." questions, hence the down votes and hold.

Comment: From the http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I can quote the following: " but if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible, especially if you want your app to be accepted into the App Store. You can detect incoming and outgoing calls using [Core Telephony](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603), but you cannot get the phone number. Plus, certain usage of the Core Telephony framework means rejection from the App Store, if that's a concern.

Comment: Thank you for your help woz! I already took a look at that framework but actually thought there could exist something else that could help. Great info on the warning about rejection on the app store!